Adding the Color Filters configuration tool to Windows 10 LTSB
(Ignore the apparent cross-post; in a moment of excitement I asked this in StackOverflow. Anyway...)
In a typical Windows 10 desktop installation, there is the Color Filters configuration function (Start > Settings > Ease of Access > Color filters), which allows the user to tweak the display colors for, say, colorblindness.
I am trying to get the Color Filters function in Windows 10 LTSB, a lightweight Windows 10 for industrial/embedded use.
Is there some way to import the Color Filters functionality into Windows 10 LTSB? Some .cpl I can grab? Is there some other relatively simple way of achieving that end?
(Btw, using Windows' retina-scorching high-contrast themes won't work, because we will be need to change the colors of a proprietary HMI.)
